# Handling external page redirection on unit testing - jasmine with code coverage

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

writing the unit testing for angular application, login mechanism works on single sing on concept, page will redirect to external url and set the cookie value for the login success (based on cookie setting local storage).

while testing that scenario browser redirects to external page and stops the unit test execution. Currently while doing the unit test commented the redirection and testing the remaining test cases.

While deploying to live again i have to uncomment the redirect code.

How can I handle this scenario in jasmine?

```
    @Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private location: Location
    ) { }

    canActivate(): boolean {
        if (!localStorage.getItem('API_TOKEN')) {
            this.redirectTOLogin();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    redirectTOLogin() {
        window.location.href = environment.appLoginUrl + environment.appUrl;
    }
}
```

> spec.ts

```
    describe('Logged in guard should', () => {
    let loggedInGuard: AuthGuard;
    const router = {
        navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
    };

    // async beforeEach
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [FormsModule, CommonModule],
            providers: [AuthGuard, Location, { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
                { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
                { provide: Router, useValue: router }
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents(); // compile template and css
    }));

    // synchronous beforeEach
    beforeEach(() => {
        loggedInGuard = TestBed.get(AuthGuard);
    });

    it('be able to hit route when user is logged in', () => {
        localStorage.setItem('API_TOKEN', 'fgsdhfhg4359854dsfsdf#@dfg4545nvnsjfjkh');
        expect(loggedInGuard.canActivate()).toBe(true);
    });

    it('not be able to hit route when user is not logged in', () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('API_TOKEN');
        spyOn(loggedInGuard, 'redirectTOLogin');
        expect(loggedInGuard.redirectTOLogin).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried mocking the window object ?

Comment: Didn't try on mocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd propose to outsource the window call into a separate function, and in the test then create a spy to check if it has been called!

What you want to test in this case is only **if** the redirect is triggered, not if the native browser functionality is actually working!

The spy jasmine creates then l prevents the actual execution of the function in the test!

```
redirect() {
   window.location.href = 'logindomainname.com?ReturnUrl=http://localhost:4200';
}

// in your test then...
spyOn(component, 'redirect');
//...
expect(component.redirect). toHaveBeenCalled();
```

EDIT:

In your first test case, I do not see a problem, this should be working and it should not redirect, as logic is not intended to.

In your second test case though, it should just fail, due to the fact that you're not calling `canActivate` at all. So the following should succeed:

```
it('not be able to hit route when user is not logged in', () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('API_TOKEN');
    spyOn(loggedInGuard, 'redirectTOLogin');

    expect(loggedInGuard.canActivate()).toBe(false);
    expect(loggedInGuard.redirectTOLogin).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

This will call `canActivate`, which should return false and calls the `redirectTOLogin` function before returning false, which is then recognized by your spy.

Comment: It's not working, page still redirecting while executing the test case.

Comment: Could you add your spec to the question, please?

Comment: Updated the both files in the question section.

Comment: Adjusted my original answer, this should resolve the issue. If there's still an issue, please add exact information on which of the two tests is failing and if there is an error emitted in the console.

Comment: redirectLogin function calling from Spy. thx. 
But still redirection function not covered through code coverage.

Comment: I would propose to test only an anchor eg: ```window.location.href = '#blah'``` the purpose of this test is simply to see if the location.href value changed. It can be achieved easily this way and the redirection won't take place.